# Surface view is not zooming

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, pinchzoom

I am working to zoom surface view, I have media player attached with surface view and also one custom view to draw on canvas. I am able to zoom custom view using this[LINK](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view). But this is not working with surface view

I use below xml code

```
<br.com.coderev.paintvideos.utils.ZoomView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
      
                <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
                <br.com.coderev.paintvideos.DrawingView
                    android:id="@+id/drawing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />
            </br.com.coderev.paintvideos.utils.ZoomView>
```

Please give me suggestions , How I zoom
surface view.